# Prompting the user for a Hyperlink

Tags: excel, database, vba, hyperlink, inputbox

Short(ish) question: I know that you can prompt the user for a string (ex. a URL), but if a user copies a hyperlink from another program (in this case a web page or an email), is it possible for the user to paste that hyperlink into an InputBox, or something similar, so that the macro can paste that into a cell in excel and retain the hyperlink format?

Details: Currently, I'm using the following macro to prompt the user to input the destination URL followed by the text to be displayed for the link:

```
Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Selection, InputBox("hyperlink destination", "add a hyperlink"), , , InputBox("text to display", "add a hyperlink")
```

However, this requires an extra step that I'm looking to avoid. Without using VBA, I can right click a link, "Copy Hyperlink", and use Ctrl+V in a cell. This automatically pastes the link with the same text displayed as the original link without requiring the user to enter that text.

Comment: Can't the user use Ctrl+V themselves?  That already works...

Comment: Yes, they could, but I'm trying to include it as part of a larger macro that prompts the user for a an ID#, Name, Date, Location, and the hypderlink.

Comment: Instead of giving them an inputbox, could you give them a "paste hyperlink" button which would trigger the paste operation?  Or a "Paste hyperlink?" Msgbox with Yes/No options.

Comment: Hm, I hadn't thought of that. I think I'll use that. Good thinking, thanks :)